# What does "Aux à la" mean?

Tags: prépositions

Some tea that I bought yesterday says the following:

[image]

> Cardamom Chai
>   Thé Aux à la Cardamome

None of the entries in the wordreference [page](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/aux) for "aux" are for adverb or adjectives.

What does "Aux" mean? Is Cardamome somehow both plural and singular feminine, causing both "aux" and "à la" to be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the bad quality of the other French translation for "foil packs inside for freshness", 
I would assume right away that it's just a translation mistake.

Nothing in French is both plural and singular in a way that would justify using both "aux" and "à" at the same time, it's just not a thing.
So definitely a translation mistake.
the right translation would be : "Thé à la cardamome"

(also "Des emballages aluminium à l'intérieur pour plus de fraîcheur" would be way better for the other one)

Comment: is using "intérieur" as an adjective as they have done grammatically correct, but perhaps not idiomatic? (i notice that wordreference does indeed list "intérieur" as an adjective, as well as a noun). what makes "à l'intérieur" more idiomatic?

Comment: It is absolutely correct and can be idiomatic, but not used as they did here. 
It's all a matter of context really, for example "il a une grande beauté intérieure (adj.)" = "he has a great inner beauty"

Comment: "Emballage intérieur aluminium pour plus de fraîcheur" is perfectly fine. Your proposed alternative is not idiomatic: we we wouldn't use a plural here unless there were multiple inner wrappings inside a single pack. Between "emballage intérieur [en] aluminium" and "emballage [en] aluminium à l'intérieur", it's a matter of whether we assume the existence of an inner wrapping beforehand or not.

Comment: @silph "Intérieur as an adjective is perfectly idiomatic here. "Aluminium" instead of "en aluminium" is not really correct but it's something a French person would write in this context.

Comment: @Gilles Could you clarify your comment about not using a plural, and "emballage intérieur [en] aluminium" vs "emballage [en] aluminium à l'intérieur"? I don't understand what you mean by "multiple inner wrappings inside a single pack" and "assume the existence of an inner wrapping beforehand or not". I know with the English, it suggests that when I open the box of tea, there are going to be multiple foil packs (and indeed, there were two sealed foil packs, each holding about 20 tea bags). Also: I'm surprised that "Emballage" could be correct even though it has no article!

Comment: @Gilles The English version uses a plural "Packs" , hence my suggestion : "des emballages" . Your translation would infer the inner side of the whole containing box is covered in aluminum, which is most probably not the case here.

Comment: @silph Sorry, I'd misread the English. Indeed, according to the English version, there are multiple sub-packages, so we'd use a plural in French. But it would still be “*Emballages intérieurs [en] aluminium*”.

Comment: @Gilles: would you be willing to try to explain the difference between "emballage à l'intérieur" and "emballage intérieur" again to me?

Comment: +1. Aux is definitely a mistake. I would not use "des emballages" because it is like a title. And as you are telling that there are "freshness packs", it would rather say "Emballages intérieurs en aluminium pour plus de fraîcheur" (the full sentence would be: "Il y a des emballages intérieurs en aluminium pour plus de fraîcheur". A noter qu'aluminium est un nom, donc pour moi la préposition "en" est nécessaire (même si on parle aussi de "papier alu" pour faire court.

Comment: Personnaly, I would say "emballages individuels en aluminum" to be clear. In the english sentence, I understand "Pssst, il y a des emballages en aluminium à l'intérieur du paquet" as if it were a "Kinder suprise", which also sounds odd to me... definitely a bad packaging...